# Show that $Y_n$ converges to zero where $Y_n=\prod X_i$ as $X_i'$'s are independent uniformly. distributed over(0,1)

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

let $X_1,X_2,....$ be independent real-valued random variables, all uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$.

Let $Y_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i$.

I want to show that $Y_n \longrightarrow 0$ almost surely.

I know theres many different ways to show that $Y_n$ converges to 0.
I have worked on one way using Borel-Cantelli condition for a.s convergence.
It state that: $$\forallε>0 : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|Y_n-0|\geq\epsilon)<\infty \implies p(|Y-0|\geq\epsilon\ \ i.o\ )=0$$ and hence: $Y_n\longrightarrow0$ almost surely.

$\bullet$ My attempt is the following :

we can write the event $(|Y_n-0|\geq\epsilon)=(Y_n\geq\epsilon)$ since $Y_n\in (0,1)$.

so for all $ε>0$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(Y_n\geq\epsilon)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{E(Y_n)}{\epsilon}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{E(X^n)}{\epsilon} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)\ \epsilon}<\infty$$
Where i used "markov inequality" in the first first inequality.

In the second equality $X_i's$ are iid unif(0,1)".

is
therefore by Borel-Cantelli this implies $\Longrightarrow P(|Y_n-0|\geq\epsilon\ \ i.o)=0$.
Which are equivalent to $P(|Y_n-0|<\epsilon \ \ evt.)=1$

And hence: $Y_n\longrightarrow 0$ a.s.

Is it right? im sure there is some mistake!

### Edit: (update:)

$\bullet $ The second equality. is not right. Since $X_1,X_2,...$ all are uniformly distributed. then the we get that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(Y_n\geq\epsilon)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{E(Y_n)}{\epsilon}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{E(\prod_{i=1}^nX_i)}{\epsilon}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n E(X_i)}{\epsilon}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{E(X_1)^n}{\epsilon} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n\ \epsilon}<\infty$$

and now: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(Y_n\geq\epsilon)<\infty \implies p(Y_n<\epsilon \ \text{evt.})=1 $
Hence, $Y_n\longrightarrow 0$ almost surely.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)}<\infty$ is surely false.

Comment: Thats right. I definitely oversaw that. Thanks

Comment: The claim $E[Y_n] = E[X^n]$ is wrong. Note that $E[Y_n] = E[ \prod_{i=1}^n X_i ] = \prod_{i=1}^n E[X_i] = \Big( \frac{1}{2} \Big)^n$, so in your last inequality you can replace the harmonic series with the convergent geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\varepsilon 2^n} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fatal mistake in your proof. The harmonic series is divergent!

$\frac 1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} ln (X_k) \to \int_0^{1} \ln x dx=-1$ almost surely by SLLN's. Hence, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} ln (X_k) \to -\infty$ a.s and taking exponential finishes the proof.